# "Too many arguments" error creating a pivot table?

Tags: sql, vb6, pivot, activereports

I want to create a pivot table in the active report to display dbf multiple
files records.

I'm trying to use the following code to create the PIVOT but it's not working, resulting in the error I've shown below.

This is the code:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Private Sub openDB()
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.Open "Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;" & _
            "Data Source=D:\Monthly\Colony;" & _
            "Collating Sequence=MACHINE"
End Sub
 Call openDB
    rs.Open "SELECT HEDNAME,DEPCODE,DEPNAME," & _
           "ISNULL(A,0) as A, ISNULL(B,0) as B, ISNULL(C,0) as C, ISNULL(G,0) as G " & _
          "from(SELECT HED.HEDCODE,HED.HEDNAME,payfil01.DEPCODE,payfil01.DEPNAME,payfil12.PARSSCB," & _
          "payfil12.EMPSHFT FROM payfil01 INNER JOIN payfil12 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil12.DEPCODE " & _
          "INNER JOIN payfil04 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil04.DEPCODE AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil04.EMPTYPE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil04.EMPCODE INNER JOIN payfil05 ON payfil12.DEPCODE = payfil05.DEPCODE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil05.EMPTYPE AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil05.EMPCODE Inner Join" & _
          "(Select DEPCODE HEDCODE,DEPNAME HEDNAME from payfil01 Where RIGHT(DEPCODE,2) = '00')" & _
          " HED On HED.HEDCODE = Left(payfil01.DEPCODE,2) + '-00' where ltrim(rtrim(payfil04.empcode))<>''" & _
          " and payfil12.parsscb>0)Final PIVOT ( SUM(PARSSCB) FOR EMPSHFT IN ([A],[B],[C],[G]) )pvt order by HEDCODE asc " & _
          ", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly"
 Set SS_Summary.DataControl1.Recordset = rs
        SS_Summary.DataControl1.Recordset = rs
                SS_Summary.Field35.Text = txtReportPeriod.Text
                SS_Summary.Show
                SS_Summary.Refresh
End Sub
```

Moreover it tried to use following query:

```
SELECT hedname, 
       depcode, 
       depname, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [empshft] = 'A' THEN parsscb 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS A, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [empshft] = 'B' THEN parsscb 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS B, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [empshft] = 'C' THEN parsscb 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS C, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN [empshft] = 'G' THEN parsscb 
             ELSE 0 
           END) AS G 
FROM  (SELECT HED.hedcode, 
              HED.hedname, 
              payfil01.depcode, 
              payfil01.depname, 
              payfil12.parsscb, 
              payfil12.empshft 
       FROM   payfil01 
              INNER JOIN payfil12 
                      ON payfil01.depcode = payfil12.depcode 
              INNER JOIN payfil04 
                      ON payfil01.depcode = payfil04.depcode 
                         AND payfil12.emptype = payfil04.emptype 
                         AND payfil12.empcode = payfil04.empcode 
              INNER JOIN payfil05 
                      ON payfil12.depcode = payfil05.depcode 
                         AND payfil12.emptype = payfil05.emptype 
                         AND payfil12.empcode = payfil05.empcode 
              INNER JOIN (SELECT depcode HEDCODE, 
                                 depname HEDNAME 
                          FROM   payfil01 
                          WHERE  RIGHT(depcode, 2) = '00') HED 
                      ON HED.hedcode = LEFT(payfil01.depcode, 2) + '-00' 
       WHERE  Ltrim(Rtrim(payfil04.empcode)) <> '' 
              AND payfil12.parsscb > 0) AS final 
GROUP  BY hedname, 
          depcode, 
          depname 
ORDER  BY depcode ASC
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: How does the second query get used by the code above?

Comment: First query code also use for secound query

Comment: @DaveInCaz please Send Me Complete Code To resolve my problem

Comment: @DaveInCaz no i am not rude please help me to send me complete code i am very thank full to you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you included some of the `Recordset.Open` parameters into the SQL string:

```
rs.Open "SELECT HEDNAME,DEPCODE,DEPNAME," & _
           "ISNULL(A,0) as A, ISNULL(B,0) as B, ISNULL(C,0) as C, ISNULL(G,0) as G " & _
          "from(SELECT HED.HEDCODE,HED.HEDNAME,payfil01.DEPCODE,payfil01.DEPNAME,payfil12.PARSSCB," & _
          "payfil12.EMPSHFT FROM payfil01 INNER JOIN payfil12 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil12.DEPCODE " & _
          "INNER JOIN payfil04 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil04.DEPCODE AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil04.EMPTYPE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil04.EMPCODE INNER JOIN payfil05 ON payfil12.DEPCODE = payfil05.DEPCODE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil05.EMPTYPE AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil05.EMPCODE Inner Join" & _
          "(Select DEPCODE HEDCODE,DEPNAME HEDNAME from payfil01 Where RIGHT(DEPCODE,2) = '00')" & _
          " HED On HED.HEDCODE = Left(payfil01.DEPCODE,2) + '-00' where ltrim(rtrim(payfil04.empcode))<>''" & _
          " and payfil12.parsscb>0)Final PIVOT ( SUM(PARSSCB) FOR EMPSHFT IN ([A],[B],[C],[G]) )pvt order by HEDCODE asc " & _
          ", cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly"  '<--- THIS PART SHOULD NOT BE IN THE STRING!!!
```

Note that last line with args for the `Open` method are accidentally in the string.  It should be more like this:

```
rs.Open "SELECT HEDNAME,DEPCODE,DEPNAME," & _
           "ISNULL(A,0) as A, ISNULL(B,0) as B, ISNULL(C,0) as C, ISNULL(G,0) as G " & _
          "from(SELECT HED.HEDCODE,HED.HEDNAME,payfil01.DEPCODE,payfil01.DEPNAME,payfil12.PARSSCB," & _
          "payfil12.EMPSHFT FROM payfil01 INNER JOIN payfil12 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil12.DEPCODE " & _
          "INNER JOIN payfil04 ON payfil01.DEPCODE = payfil04.DEPCODE AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil04.EMPTYPE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil04.EMPCODE INNER JOIN payfil05 ON payfil12.DEPCODE = payfil05.DEPCODE" & _
          " AND payfil12.EMPTYPE = payfil05.EMPTYPE AND payfil12.EMPCODE = payfil05.EMPCODE Inner Join" & _
          "(Select DEPCODE HEDCODE,DEPNAME HEDNAME from payfil01 Where RIGHT(DEPCODE,2) = '00')" & _
          " HED On HED.HEDCODE = Left(payfil01.DEPCODE,2) + '-00' where ltrim(rtrim(payfil04.empcode))<>''" & _
          " and payfil12.parsscb>0)Final PIVOT ( SUM(PARSSCB) FOR EMPSHFT IN ([A],[B],[C],[G]) )pvt order by HEDCODE asc " & _
          , cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: Please send me complete solution of my problem

Comment: how i manage pivot in this query? send me complete solution of my code thanks